# How can I copy cells in Excel 2007 and paste with formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am wanting to be able to copy cells in a worksheet and paste them elsewhere in the same worksheet while maintaining the original formatting.  I also want to be able to paste into Word and Outlook and keep the same formatting.

Everything I have tried discards the the formatting and only pastes unformatted text.

Paste Option buttons do not appear even though they have been defined in the setting to appear.  Also Format Painter does not seem to do anything at all.

Is there a setting that needs to be changed to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Excel Options** and in the **"Advanced"** Section there is a paragraph called **"Cut, Copy and Paste"**. There you can find an option to **"show Paste Options"**.
That disables or enables the little menu that pops up when you paste something. The default is to show it and to copy formatting however. Not sure how that got lost in your Excel.