# Excel 2007 suddenly does not paste with formatting anymore

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, copy-paste

A friend's Excel 2007 used to, when you'd copy cells and paste them within a document, paste the formatting along with it.

Suddenly today it no longer does that.

I found this question: [How can I copy cells in Excel 2007 and paste with formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/516477/how-can-i-copy-cells-in-excel-2007-and-paste-with-formatting) but the answer given is something my friend already tried, and even with that option enabled, no paste dialog appears when you paste.

Why did this change all of the sudden?  Windows Update?  How can we get the normal behaviour back?  *My friend does not even want the dialog box,* and it *was* working, hence the new question here.  It just used to paste with formatting when you pasted.  That's all.

Comment: Restarting now.

Comment: That did it.  Gosh.  I thought such things disappeared with Windows 98, didn't expect them on a half-year-old Win7 box.  Thanks...

Comment: Just rebooting.  My friend doesn't have any macros in use.  I don't think anything was recently installed, but I'll look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic Windows solution: reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Skype (i.e. Skype Click to Call) is known to make problems with office formatting. Try uninstalling/updating them both, if you have them. Some other ideas can be found [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/my-format-painter-in-excel-2010-has-stopped/f4863ace-8ac5-4c42-9838-8bbc8efb6ec1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's insane!  Thanks for the link.  I will try this after it boots up.

Comment: Though I didn't end up needing to try this, it's good to know.  I think to be safe I'll get rid of click to call whenever I come across it.